# Reading file from different directory with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want something like this:

If a request comes to `domain.com/photos/1.jpg` it should read file from `new_photos/1.jpg` directory. But url should still look same. I tried with this line to do this:

```
RewriteRule ^photos/(.*)$ new_photos/?$1
```

It doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Edit:

My full htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/?$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-subdomain.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If the  file is in /new_photos dir ,You can use this :

```
RewriteRule ^photos/(.*)$ new_photos/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I can't see the code clearly, please edit your question to post the code.

Comment: Where is this htaccess located?

Comment: Root directory. I mean public_html